What volume formula does it refer to?
Question:
In pentahedron $ABC-DEF$, we know that $AD\|BE\|CF$, and the distance between them is $1$. We also know that $AD=1,BE=2,CF=3$.
What is the volume of the pentahedron?
Answer:
Analysis:According the the volume formula of the trapezoid, the required volume is:
$$\frac{\sqrt3}4\cdot1^2\cdot\frac{1+2+3}3=\frac{\sqrt3}2$$
What volume formula does it refer to?

Please do not use images for crucial parts of your question. We suggest editing the question to include them as text/math equations.

(Alternative) hint: The prism below of height 6 over an equilateral unit triangle is composed of three shapes that match the description.


Thank you very much, this means a lot to me.

In this particular case I think it could be done with just two pentahedra, but this figure shows how to solve the volume for any three lengths.

In general, suppose the distances between $AD,BE,CF$ are $d_1,d_2,d_3$, forming a triangle of area $S$, the lengths of $AD,BE,CF$ are $h_1,h_2,h_3$, then we have:
$$ V=S\cdot \frac{h_1+h_2+h_3}{3}$$
This is analogous to the formula of the area of a (2-dim) trapezoid. You may try to prove it yourself, if you need help I am also glad to provide my proof.
